# How to compare a varchar column with multiple values

Tags: sql-server-2016

Is there a way to compare a column with a list of expressions? This is my current code:

```
WHERE    
   [Description] like 'c:DEC%' 
   or [Description] like 'c:DTI%' 
   or [Description] like 'c:DCT%' 
   or [Description] like 'c:DTB%' 
   or [Description] like 'c:DTX%'
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
Where [Description] like ('c:DTI%','c:DCT%','c:DTB%','c:DTX%')
```

Comment: What is the issue with the current query ?

Comment: I do not only have thos 5 comparisons, but more than a hundred. It gets confusing the longer the query gets.

Comment: If you are passing them through from a client app, put them in a Table-Valued parameter (basically a table variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it in a temp table

```
create table #temp
(
    descript varchar(100)
)

insert into #temp (descript) values
('c:DTI%') , ('c:DCT%'), ('c:DTB%'), ('c:DTX%');

SELECT *
FROM   yourtable d 
       INNER JOIN #temp t    ON    d.[Description] LIKE t.descript
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this would be best implemented with a correlation rather than multiple hard-coded conditions, especially if you have hundreds!

You could have a table - either permanent or a `table-valued-parameter` passed to your procedure, and implement your filtering using `exists`

```
from MyTable t
where ...
and exists (select * from LookupTable l where t.[description] like l.MatchText)
```